# Cannot send image to the server using angular-file-upload

Tags: angularjs, laravel

I am trying to upload a image file from my angularjs app to my API which is built in Laravel and my html page looks like this:

```
                <label for="">Import from file:</label>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <input type="file" nv-file-select="" multiple="false" uploader="uploader"/>
                        <br><br>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div ng-repeat="item in uploader.queue">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" ng-click="item.upload()"
                                    ng-disabled="item.isReady || item.isUploading || item.isSuccess">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></span> Upload
                            </button>
                            <br><br>
                        </div>

                        {{uploadStatus}}
                    </div>
                </div>
```

In my Controller I have the following code:

```
var uploader = $scope.uploader = new FileUploader({
            url: REST_END_POINT + 'businesses/158',
            method: 'PUT',
            headers: {
                Authorization: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('satellizer_token')
            },
            formData: []
        });
```

And my Api function at the moment looks like this:

```
    $file = $request->file('file');
    if ($file) {
        return response()->json('file exists');
        try {
            Storage::put('/teams/businesses/logo/' . $business->team_id . '/' . $file->getClientOriginalName(), File::get($file));
            $business->logo = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return response()->json(['Something went wrong while uploading the file' => 'Error', 'success' => false, 'status' => 500, 'data' => $e]);
        }
    }else{
        return response()->json('file !exists');
    }
```

So when I try to submit from Angularjs App it prints "file !exists". So the file is not existing and I dont know why.

the api router looks as:

`Route::put('businesses/{id}', ['as' => 'update_business', 'uses' => 'BusinessController@update']);`

Do you have any idea what is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0):

In your php code you are `return`ing a response before you attempt to store the file. The `return` statement halts execution of the script.

```
$file = $request->file('file');
if ($file) {
    return response()->json('file exists'); // execution stops here
    // might as well comment all of this out...it will never execute
    //try {
    //    Storage::put('/teams/businesses/logo/' . $business->team_id . '/' . $file->getClientOriginalName(), File::get($file));
    //    $business->logo = $file->getClientOriginalName();
    //} catch (\Exception $e) {
    //    return response()->json(['Something went wrong while uploading the file' => 'Error', 'success' => false, 'status' => 500, 'data' => $e]);
    //}
}else{
    return response()->json('file !exists');
}
```

You want to do something a little more along the lines of this:

```
// Don't overwrite the file if it already exists
if ($file = $request->file('file')) {
    return response()->json('file exists');
}

// File does not exist. Go ahead and attempt to save it.
try {
    Storage::put('/teams/businesses/logo/' . $business->team_id . '/' . $file->getClientOriginalName(), File::get($file));
    $business->logo = $file->getClientOriginalName();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    return response()->json(['Something went wrong while uploading the file' => 'Error', 'success' => false, 'status' => 500, 'data' => $e]);
}

return response()->json('file uploaded successfully');
```